# Getting Error in running contact Report

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, civireport

I am using Hostgator shared hosting for CIVI CRM and Drupal.From few days, I am getting an error that Error writing file '/var/mysqltmp/MYCckA2E' (Errcode: 28)".

I tried to change the queries and removed the order by clause.The query is working in phpmyadmin but there is an error in civi website.

**Please help me with this issue.your suggestions are most welcome.**

function query($string)
    {

if (strpos(trim($string), 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_sort_name, contact_civireport.id as civicrm_contact_id FROM civicrm_contact contact_civireport WHERE ( contact_civireport.is_deceased LIKE 0 ) ORDER BY contact_civireport.sort_name ASC LIMIT 0, 10') == false)
{
$string=str_replace("ORDER BY contact_civireport.sort_name ASC","","SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_sort_name, contact_civireport.id as civicrm_contact_id FROM civicrm_contact contact_civireport WHERE ( contact_civireport.is_deceased LIKE 0 ) ORDER BY contact_civireport.sort_name ASC LIMIT 0, 10");
echo $string;
        return $this->_query($string);
        }
        else
        return $this->_query($string);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Check if `www-data` has write permissions in `/var/mysqltmp` directory.

Comment: I don't have access to this folder as I am working on shared hosting.